# How to DRY These JS Math Computations

Tags: javascript, math, dry, computation

I have these math computations below that are repetitive and I am trying to figure out how to make them DRY.

```js
const d     = store.state.logbook.summary,
      AIR   = ([d.AIR/d.TOT]*100).toFixed(2),
      PIC   = ([d.PIC/d.TOT]*100).toFixed(2),
      PMC   = ([d.PMC/d.TOT]*100).toFixed(2),
      VO    = ([d.VO/d.TOT]*100).toFixed(2),
      TRNG  = ([d.TRNG/d.TOT]*100).toFixed(2);

this.chartData = [
  100, +AIR, +PIC, +PMC, +VO, +TRNG
]
console.log(this.chartData)
// Returns: [100, 97.44, 84.65, 84.65, 2.56, 12.79]!
```

Comment: Don't use `[...]` as inner grouping. Yes, it works in this case in particular because JavaScript stringifies the unit array as the numeric string and then `*` casts it back to a number, but that's _really_ bad practice.

Comment: What exactly aere you trying to DRY?  the `toFixed` the `*100`?  Look into a `reduce` function.

Comment: Thnx @PatrickRoberts Doing math in js is a new world for me - good to know.

Comment: looks like it would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Codereview is for "opinionated" questions. This is something that others can learn from as-well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an array of the keys, mapthe calculated value, unshift `100` and assign to the wanted target.

```
const
    d = store.state.logbook.summary,
    data = ['AIR', 'PIC', 'PMC', 'VO', 'TRNG'].map(k => +(d[k] * 100 / d.TOT).toFixed(2));

data.unshift(100);
this.chartData = data;
console.log(this.chartData);
```

Just another view of the problem by splitting each part into a smaller units, like

- getting the value of the object
- get the percent value by taking a bound first parameter of the function and mapping the values
- format the value to wanted max two digits.

```js
const
    getPercent = (whole, part) => part * 100 / whole,
    getNumFixed2 = value => +value.toFixed(2),
    d = { AIR: 28, PIC: 9, PMC: 2, VO: 56, TRNG: 25, TOT: 120 }, // store.state.logbook.summary,
    data = ['AIR', 'PIC', 'PMC', 'VO', 'TRNG']
        .map(k => d[k])
        .map(getPercent.bind(null, d.TOT))
        .map(getNumFixed2);

data.unshift(100);
console.log(data);
```